Qt/C++ Convert a quadrilateral (trapezoid) into a rectangle without additional libraries
Is it possible to transform an image of an arbitrary quadrilateral into a rectangle of a given size using QTransform?

This task is available for Android - Create rectangle bitmap from trapezoid crop
The response uses SkMatrix and the method
setPolyToPoly (const Sk Point src[], const SkPoint dst[], int count)

https://github.com/google/skia/blob/main/src/core/SkMatrix.cpp
which seems to form a matrix of modifiers over the src quadrilateral in order to make a dst quadrilateral out of it later (I understand there). I did not find a similar method in QTransform.
I rewrote these codes in c++ and Qtransform. I took into account that the position constants in SkMatrix differ from QTranform. But when I try to apply the QTransform obtained by my function, I get an unpredictable result on the screen. Maybe I made a mistake in the codes or am I applying the result incorrectly?
// SkMatrix Constants
static constexpr int kMScaleX   = 0; //!< horizontal scale factor
static constexpr int kMSkewX    = 1; //!< horizontal skew factor
static constexpr int kMTransX   = 2; //!< horizontal translation
static constexpr int kMSkewY    = 3; //!< vertical skew factor
static constexpr int kMScaleY   = 4; //!< vertical scale factor
static constexpr int kMTransY   = 5; //!< vertical translation
static constexpr int kMPersp0   = 6; //!< input x perspective factor
static constexpr int kMPersp1   = 7; //!< input y perspective factor
static constexpr int kMPersp2   = 8; //!< perspective bias

// Constants for Qt
static constexpr int qtScaleX       = 0; // 11 // scale
static constexpr int qtSkewY        = 1; // 12 // shear
static constexpr int qtPerspY       = 2; // 13 // влияет rotate вокгуг YAxias / = Persp1
static constexpr int qtSkewX        = 3; // 21 // shear
static constexpr int qtScaleY       = 4; // 22 // scale
static constexpr int qtPerspX       = 5; // 23 // влияет rotate вокгуг XAxias / = Persp0
static constexpr int qtTransX       = 6; // 31 // translate
static constexpr int qtTransY       = 7; // 32 // translate
static constexpr int qtPerspZ       = 8; // 33 // не удалось повлиять на значение / = Persp2
/*
  ScaleX     SkewY     PerspY
  SkewX      ScaleY    PerspX
  TransX     TransY    PerspZ
 */

void convertSkToQt(const QTransform& skSrc, QTransform& qtDst)
{
    QList<qreal> skLine(9, 0);
    skLine[kMScaleX   ] = skSrc.m11();
    skLine[kMSkewX    ] = skSrc.m21();
    skLine[kMTransX   ] = skSrc.m31();
    skLine[kMSkewY    ] = skSrc.m12();
    skLine[kMScaleY   ] = skSrc.m22();
    skLine[kMTransY   ] = skSrc.m32();
    skLine[kMPersp0   ] = skSrc.m23();
    skLine[kMPersp1   ] = skSrc.m13();
    skLine[kMPersp2   ] = skSrc.m33();

    /*
                ScaleX     SkewY     PerspY
                SkewX      ScaleY    PerspX
                TransX     TransY    PerspZ
    */
    qtDst.setMatrix(
        skLine[kMScaleX ], skLine[kMSkewY ], skLine[kMPersp1   ]
      , skLine[kMSkewX  ], skLine[kMScaleY], skLine[kMPersp0   ]
      , skLine[kMTransX ], skLine[kMTransY], skLine[kMPersp2   ]
    );
}

bool poly4Proc(const QList<QPointF>& srcPt, QTransform& dst) {
    qreal a1, a2;
    qreal x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2;
    x0 = srcPt[2].x() - srcPt[0].x();
    y0 = srcPt[2].y() - srcPt[0].y();
    x1 = srcPt[2].x() - srcPt[1].x();
    y1 = srcPt[2].y() - srcPt[1].y();
    x2 = srcPt[2].x() - srcPt[3].x();
    y2 = srcPt[2].y() - srcPt[3].y();
    /* check if abs(x2) > abs(y2) */
    if ( x2 > 0 ? y2 > 0 ? x2 > y2 : x2 > -y2 : y2 > 0 ? -x2 > y2 : x2 < y2) {
        float denom = sk_ieee_float_divide(x1 * y2, x2) - y1;
        if (checkForZero(denom)) {
            return false;
        }
        a1 = (((x0 - x1) * y2 / x2) - y0 + y1) / denom;
    } else {
        float denom = x1 - sk_ieee_float_divide(y1 * x2, y2);
        if (checkForZero(denom)) {
            return false;
        }
        a1 = (x0 - x1 - sk_ieee_float_divide((y0 - y1) * x2, y2)) / denom;
    }
    /* check if abs(x1) > abs(y1) */
    if ( x1 > 0 ? y1 > 0 ? x1 > y1 : x1 > -y1 : y1 > 0 ? -x1 > y1 : x1 < y1) {
        float denom = y2 - sk_ieee_float_divide(x2 * y1, x1);
        if (checkForZero(denom)) {
            return false;
        }
        a2 = (y0 - y2 - sk_ieee_float_divide((x0 - x2) * y1, x1)) / denom;
    } else {
        float denom = sk_ieee_float_divide(y2 * x1, y1) - x2;
        if (checkForZero(denom)) {
            return false;
        }
        a2 = (sk_ieee_float_divide((y0 - y2) * x1, y1) - x0 + x2) / denom;
    }

    QList<qreal> lineMatrix(9, 0);
    lineMatrix[kMScaleX] = a2 * srcPt[3].x() + srcPt[3].x() - srcPt[0].x();
    lineMatrix[kMSkewY]  = a2 * srcPt[3].y() + srcPt[3].y() - srcPt[0].y();
    lineMatrix[kMPersp0] = a2;
    lineMatrix[kMSkewX]  = a1 * srcPt[1].x() + srcPt[1].x() - srcPt[0].x();
    lineMatrix[kMScaleY] = a1 * srcPt[1].y() + srcPt[1].y() - srcPt[0].y();
    lineMatrix[kMPersp1] = a1;
    lineMatrix[kMTransX] = srcPt[0].x();
    lineMatrix[kMTransY] = srcPt[0].y();
    lineMatrix[kMPersp2] = 1;

    dst.setMatrix(  lineMatrix[0], lineMatrix[1], lineMatrix[2]
                  , lineMatrix[3], lineMatrix[4], lineMatrix[5]
                  , lineMatrix[6], lineMatrix[7], lineMatrix[8]
    );

    return true;
}

bool setPolyToPoly(QTransform& matrix, const QList<QPointF>& src, const QList<QPointF>& dst)
{
    QTransform tempMap, result;
    if (!poly4Proc(src, tempMap))
        return false;

    bool done = false;
    result = tempMap.inverted(&done);
    if (!done) {
        qDebug().noquote() << "Can't invert matrix:" << tempMap;
        return false;
    }

    if (!poly4Proc(dst, tempMap))
        return false;

    QTransform matrixRes0 =  tempMap * result;

    convertSkToQt(matrixRes0, matrix);

    return true;
}

void test()
{
    painter->save();

    QTransform polyToPolymatrix;
    int deform = 20;

    QList<QPointF> src(4, QPointF(0, 0));
        src[0] = QPointF(0, 0);
        src[1] = QPointF(200, 0);
        src[2] = QPointF(200, 200);
        src[3] = QPointF(0, 200);

    QList<QPointF> dst(4, QPointF(0, 0));
        dst[0] = QPointF(0, 0);
        dst[1] = QPointF(200-deform, deform);
        dst[2] = QPointF(200-deform, 200-deform);
        dst[3] = QPointF(0, 200);

    setPolyToPoly(polyToPolymatrix, src, dst);

    painter->setTransform(polyToPolymatrix);

    painter->drawPixmap(QPointF(0, 0), m_pixmap, QRectF(0, 0, 200, 200));

    painter->restore();
}


QTransform is just 3 by 3 matrix and your transformation can be handled by matrix. The whole problem is just calculate elements of this matrix. Infact Qt provides ready function for this: QTransform::quadToQuad.

@MarekR I don't understand. how could I miss this (  thanks a lot
